# how to send variable value to nsmutable array in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to send variable string value to nsmutable array in objective c?

If `global` is my `NSMutableArray` and `temp` is variable containing string,
then

```
[global addObject:@"%@",temp];
```

is not working pls check out guys and reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add some formatted string you can use like this

```
[global addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp]];
```

otherwise [DrummerB answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14055281/468724) is absolutely valid.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the object.

```
[global addObject:temp];
```

Why are you trying to use a [string format specifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object first.

It may be a `NSString` ( as in your case ), or may be any such thing like array, dictionary etc.

Then add it to the array. But the array must be a `NSMutableArray`.

```
[global addObject:yourObject]; //will add at last
```

or

```
[global addObject:yourObject atIndex:desiredIndex];//insert at the given index
```

If it is string, you can use many of the methods available under string class to form,, like `initWithString`, `stringWithFormat` etc.

```
NSString *yourObject=.....;//create an object using any of the class or instance method of NSString.
```